# (GitHub Actions, Cypress run fails to record outputs): `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/__w/**`

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, github-actions, npx

I'm trying to execute a cypress run job on GitHub Actions and I encounter the following issue:

```
Warning: We failed to record the video.

This error will not alter the exit code.
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/__w/{{repo-name}}/{{repo-name}}/cypress/videos/'
```

Here is a snippet of my .yml file:

```
      - name: Run Cypress tests
    run: |
      if [ ! -z ${{env.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY}} ]; then
          npx cypress run -P ${{env.CYPRESS_PROJECT_PATH}} -C ${{env.CYPRESS_CONFIG_FILE}} -r ${{env.CYPRESS_REPORTER}} ${{env.ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS}} --record
      else
          npx cypress run -P ${{env.CYPRESS_PROJECT_PATH}} -C ${{env.CYPRESS_CONFIG_FILE}} -r ${{env.CYPRESS_REPORTER}} ${{env.ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS}}
      fi
    env:
      CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY}}
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        
  - name: Archive Cypress outputs
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      # Artifact name. Optional, default is artifact
      name: cypress-outputs
      path: |
        cypress/videos/
        cypress/screenshots/
      if-no-files-found: error
      retention-days: 15
```

The error happens when the job reaches the `npx cypress run` section.

Comment: Are you able to execute your Cypress tests locally and record Video without issues? Are all necessary environment variables set correctly?

Comment: @SebastianoVierk, yes, all tests and records are well done locally.